# C: multi while loops and variables

Tags: c, while-loop

Well here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(){
   int n=728,sum = 0, remainder, sump=0, d=2;

   while(n>d){
    if(n%d==0){
        n/=d;
        sump= sump+d;
    }
    else{
        d++;
        }
   }
   sump=sump+d%10+d/10;
   printf("%d\n",sump);

   while(n != 0){
      remainder = n % 10;
      sum = sum + remainder;
      n = n / 10;
   }
   printf("%d\n",sum);
   return 0;
}
```

Here is what I get when I run the code:

```
17
4
```

The problem is that although the *sump* is correct because the sum of `728` prime factors digits is `(2+2+2+7+1+3=17)` the *sum* of digits of `728` is `4` instead of `17` which means that in the second while loop `n` is equal to `13` which is the last prime factor from the first loop.

**What's my mistake and in the second loop `n` is `13` and not `728`?**

Please forgive me if my english is bad :S

Comment: so what is this program supposed to do?

Comment: You didn't store the value of `n`. try displaying it after the first `while` loop.

Comment: Please get the indentation correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `n` is no longer be the `728` after the first `while` loop. In second `while` loop you are extracting the digits of `n` and then trying to add them but those digits are not `7, 2` and `8`.
Try this:

```
int temp = n; 
 ...
while(temp != 0){
     remainder = temp % 10;
     sum = sum + remainder;
     temp = temp / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're clearly modifying n inside your first while loop.

You can reassign 728 to N before the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

In the first while loop you are changing the value of n, that's why you are getting a "wrong" value. Either keep a copy of n or refactor your code to use functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(){
int n=728,sum = 0, remainder, sump=0, d=2;
int tempn=n;
while(n>d){
if(n%d==0){
    n/=d;
    sump= sump+d;
}
else{
    d++;
    }
 }
sump=sump+d%10+d/10;
printf("%d\n",sump);
n=tempn;
while(n != 0){
  remainder = n % 10;
  sum = sum + remainder;
  n = n / 10;
}
printf("%d\n",sum);
return 0;
}
```